# Java 1.5 crash on AIX 5

Tags: aix, java-5

I have a problem with **Java 1.5.0** for **AIX**. The error happens just when I log on with specific user on AIX (*myuser*). When I log on with other user java works ok.

The error come up even when I executed just **"java -version"** or simply **"java"** (of course, without quoting). I've tried executing it with the full path: **/usr/java5/jre/bin/java** but still fails.

There was installed the version 1.4 of java on system too. So the **$PATH** variable for the user contained ***/usr/java14/jre/bin***, but I removed that value, I even uninstalled that version of java (1.4) so that just java 5 exists on the system, but the error continues.

If I execute **"java -fullversion"** it doesn't crash.

This is part of the error (the full output is very long):

```
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9dmp23: No such file or directory
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9jit23: No such file or directory
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9gc23: No such file or directory
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load j9vrb23: No such file or directory
Unhandled exception
Type=Illegal instruction vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000010 Signal_Number=00000004 Error_Value=00000000
Signal_Code=0000001e
Handler1=F0719CC8 Handler2=F0714F5C
.....
Target=2_30_20091103_45935_bHdSMr (AIX 5.3)
CPU=ppc (4 logical CPUs) (0x7d0000000 RAM)

JavaVMInitArgs.nOptions=14:
    -Xjcl:jclscar_23
    -Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=/usr/java5/jre/bin
    -Dsun.boot.library.path=/usr/java5/jre/bin
    -Djava.library.path=/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/jre/bin/classic:/usr/java5/jre/bin:/sqllib/lib:/home/myuser/comm:/home/myuser/sys:/home/myuser/bin:/db2util/db2adm/sqllib/lib64:/usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm:/usr/lib
    -Djava.home=/usr/java5/jre
    -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/java5/jre/lib/ext
    -Duser.dir=/home/myuser
    _j2se_j9=70912 (extra info: F070EA2C)
    -Xdump
    vfprintf (extra info: 300017A4)
    -Dinvokedviajava
    -Djava.class.path=/db2util/db2adm/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/db2util/db2adm/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:/db2util/db2adm/sqllib/java/sqlj.zip:/db2util/db2adm/sqllib/function:/db2util/db2adm/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:.
    vfprintf
    _port_library (extra info: F070EE30)
Note: "Enable full CORE dump" in smit is set to FALSE and as a result there will be limited threading information in core file.
Note: dump may be truncated if "ulimit -c" is set too low
Generated system dump: {default OS core name}

(no Thread object associated with thread)

(no Thread object associated with thread)
Unhandled exception in signal handler
ksh: 2179192 IOT/Abort trap(coredump)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. The problem is a line on the .profile which sets the environment variable LIBPATH:

```
export LIBPATH=/home/myuser/sys
```

I deleted that line in the .profile and java worked.

Comment: Which library was in that directory and made Java crash? Just for curiosity.

Comment: On the path that was creating conflicts there are several .so files of a program called CS2